# Issue with Chaining activities in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have situation of chaining the activities and it doesn't work in below case:

1. Web1 success is linked to Web2
2. Web1 failure is linked to SetVariable1
3. Web2 success is linked to Web3
4. SetVariable1 success is also linked to Web3

**Issue**: In any of the condition or run path, Web3 is never reached.

In the below situation, as SetVariable1 is a success, I assume it should execute Web3, but it didn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web3 is dependent on success of Web2 and SetVariable1.

Web3 will be executed only when Web2 and SetVariable1 are successfully run.

Hope this resolves your issue- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/511483/issue-with-chaining-activities.html